Pass local variables to methods in R >= 4.4.0
From ?UseMethod (also in the NEWS file):

UseMethod creates a new function call with arguments matched as they came in to the generic.  [Previously local variables defined before the call to UseMethod were retained; as of R 4.4.0 this is no longer the case.]

With this dummy generic and its methods:
f <- function(x) {
  y <- head(x, 1)
  z <- tail(x, 1)
  UseMethod("f")
}

f.numeric <- function(x) {
  x + y + z
}

f.character <- function(x) {
  paste(x, y, z)
}

In R >= 4.4.0, we have:
f(1:3)
# Error in f.numeric(1:3) : object 'y' not found

f(c("a", "b", "c"))
# Error in f.character(c("a", "b", "c")) : object 'y' not found

While in R < 4.4.0, we had:
f(1:3)
# [1] 5 6 7

f(c("a", "b", "c"))
# [1] "a a c" "b a c" "c a c"

What is now the recommended way to pass local variables to methods?
My use case involves several objects that are precomputed from x before the call to UseMethod(). I am wondering if there is an alternative to wrapping this step in a function that would be called in each method, e.g.:
f <- function(x) {
  UseMethod("f")
}

g <- function(x) {
  y <- head(x, 1)
  z <- tail(x, 1)
  list(y = y, z = z)
}

f.numeric <- function(x) {
  yz <- g(x)
  x + yz$y + yz$z
}

f.character <- function(x) {
  yz <- g(x)
  paste(x, yz$y, yz$z)
}

This remain less practical than the former behavior because objects are now nested in a list. Anyway, I wish to avoid code duplication in the methods because the common step is relatively long (in LOC not time).

Why is this necessary? Why can't these variables be computed in the methods? I can't imagine a valid reason. From a user's perspective, it doesn't make a difference. Performance is the same.

I wish to avoid code duplication so I thought of either use a function in the method or compute y and z in the generic. I am not saying it is necessary, I am looking for good practice.

How about this?
f <- function(x) {
  y <- head(x, 1)
  z <- tail(x, 1)
  f_int(x, y, z)
}

f_int <- function(x, ...)   UseMethod("f_int")

f_int.numeric <- function(x, y, z, ...) {
  x + y + z
}

f_int.character <- function(x, y, z, ...) {
  paste(x, y, z)
}

f(1:3)
#[1] 5 6 7

f(c("a", "b", "c"))
#[1] "a a c" "b a c" "c a c"


What you appear to want is that f() and f.numeric() share an environment.  So why not make that explicit, by defining both of them in an enclosing environment?  Here's one way to do that:
# Create a local environment to be the common environment of the two 
# functions

fns <- local({
  # Create a dummy variable to hold the common local variable
  y <- NULL 

  f <- function(x) {
    # Modify the common variable
    y <<- 10
 
    # Dispatch to the method
    UseMethod("f")
  }

  f.numeric <- function(x) {
    # This function can see both the argument x and y in the enclosing
    # environment
    x + y
  }

  # Base R doesn't have "multi-assign", so we put these functions in a list
  list(f = f, f.numeric = f.numeric)
})

# Extract the two functions we just created.
f <- fns$f
f.numeric <- fns$f.numeric

f(1)
#> [1] 11

Created on 2024-06-03 with reprex v2.1.0
There are some issues with this approach.  Perhaps you don't want those two definitions in the same file.  Then you could change it to this:
f <- local({
  y <- NULL 

  function(x) {
    y <<- 10
    UseMethod("f")
  }
})

f.numeric <- function(x) {
  x + y
}
environment(f.numeric) <- environment(f)

f(1)
#> [1] 11

Created on 2024-06-03 with reprex v2.1.0
Now you only need to be sure that the definitions of both f and f.numeric happen before setting the environment.  That can be done by forcing the collation sequence of your files, or putting the environment change into a zzz.R file.
I'd recommend against the second approach.  Since both f() and f.numeric() are working on some common variables, it makes sense to me that they should be defined in the same source file.  It would be really easy to change the local variables in f() without updating f.numeric() if they weren't.

+1 and thank you for proposing different approach. However, it seems more complicated than wrapping the preprocessing in a function to be called in each method. (I will update my question to better reflect my use case; the common variable y is in fact derived from x so it can easely be done in a function called in the methods.)

Sure, that would work too.

If you  went with your approach by preparation with g() and those interim results in a list object; you could simplify the syntax to drop the $ calls with something like
f <- function(x) {
  UseMethod("f")
}

g <- function(x) {
  y <- head(x, 1)
  z <- tail(x, 1)
  list(y = y, z = z)
}

f.numeric <- function(x) {
  with(g(x),{
    x + y + z
  })
}

f.character <- function(x) {
  with(g(x),{
  paste(x, y, z)
  })
}

f(1)
f("1")


Thanks! However, I do not think we can call this recommanded. From ?with: "For interactive use this is very effective and nice to read. For programming however, i.e., in one's functions, more care is needed, and typically one should refrain from using with(), as, e.g., variables in data may accidentally override local variables, see the reference."
