Retaining local variables defined before the call to `UseMethod` in R ≥ 4.4.0
I've a generic S3 function in which I declare a variable that must be accessible from the different child methods.
For example:
that <- function(x) {
  this <- 10
  UseMethod("that")
}

that.foo <- function(x) {
  this * x
}

that.bar <- function(x) {
  this / x
}

x <- structure(5, class = "foo")
that(x)

This code no longer works as of R 4.4.0.
Is there any simple workaround to make it work again?

There's no way that code worked in any previous version of R, I have just tested with R-4.2.1 and R-4.3.1 and it didn't work, the error was exactly the same. Are you sure that you didn't have a variable this in your global env?

This worked in a previous versions of R, I'm sure about that. Can't tell you exactly when this stopped working. There's an example in Hadley's Advance R book that confirms it: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#exercises-40 (exercice 5). In that example g(x) returns a value of 10 for y. With my current version of R, y is 1.

In UseMethod() documentation, one can read: Previously local variables defined before the call to UseMethod were retained; as of R 4.4.0 this is no longer the case. Sadly, they don't give a workaround for this which is crazy since that's completely breaking old codes…

Found another post asking that question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78571315/pass-local-variables-to-methods-in-r-4-4-0

You are right, my error. And I don't have an answer to the question.

The obvious workaround is to use this = 10 as a default argument to the methods that need it. You should also include a this argument in the generic method
that <- function(x, this, ...) {
  UseMethod("that")
}

that.foo <- function(x, this = 10, ...) {
  this * x
}

that.bar <- function(x, this = 10, ...) {
  this / x
}

x <- structure(5, class = "foo")

that(x)
#> [1] 50
#> attr(,"class")
#> [1] "foo"


Of course, with such a basic example, that's how you'd design the methods but that doesn't answer my initial question: "how to retain variables defined in the generic function". I ended up using Roland's answer in the link I posted above.

@Junitar a wrapping function still requires the "internal" method to have multiple arguments that have to be included in each method. I'm not sure what this extra level of misdirection achieves? Also, the answer as given by Roland works but will not pass CRAN checks because the generic and methods must have exactly the same arguments.

The wrapping function needs the arguments but not the generic, that makes a big difference. Imagine you have a S3 class that produces a plot and you would like to add and display model outputs in slightly different ways for distinct analyses. The basis for the plot will be the same. It wouldn't make sense to define it in the global environment because it has no meaning there. Instead you can build the plot in the generic and tweak it in the child methods. I don't need this for a CRAN project so I'm fine with that.
